# Sql query to select every distinct and last row along with other columns which are retrieved using inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm starting with sql language so I'll try to specify my problem at my very best. I've been reading other questions, but no one seems to fit for me. So...

I need to find the last paid price of each Item at each supplier from the InventoryEntriesDetail table.

As the table InventoryEntriesDetail contains both sales and purchases documents, I've joined InventoryEntriesDetail table to the InventoryEntries table and filtered it to get only the purchases docs.

Now I have several rows with:supplier, item, date, docNr, etc. . But i need only the last record from each supplier / item.

Any suggestions ?

---

As requested, here is where I get so far

```
SELECT 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.CustSupp as Supplier, 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.Item as Item, 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.PostingDate as Date,
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.InvRsn AS InvRsn, 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.Qty as Qty, 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.UnitValue as Price, 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.DiscountFormula as Discount, 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.EntryId as ID
FROM 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MA_InventoryEntries 
        ON dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.EntryId = dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.EntryId
WHERE 
    dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.CustSuppType = 6094849
ORDER BY 
    Supplier, 
    Item, 
    Date
```

Some notes:

- the last EntryId is not always the record that i'm searching for
- the left join is a 'must' beacuse the InventoryEntriesDetail was completed with the InvRsn only a few years ago (and it always been in InventoryEntries (not detail))
- the DB I'm using has its first records back on 2001, so the tables we are joining have over 11mln records

PS: thanks Chris Albert for correcting the question. Now its much more clear. :)

Comment: my first suggestion would be that you edit you question and add some code. what you have done and what's not working. otherwise the question is not clear enough to answer.

Comment: @Rabanito you need a little more info in your question

Comment: What's your current query? You could do it with at row_number() over (partition by supplier, item order by date desc) and select where this is equal to 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to identify the last record per `supplier, item` partition:

```
SELECT supplier, item, date, docNr, qty, price, DiscountFormula
FROM (
   SELECT supplier, item, date, docNr, qty, price, DiscountFormula
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY supplier, item 
                             ORDER BY date DESC) AS rn
   FROM yourtable )
WHERE t.rn = 1
```

You can use `RANK()` in place of `ROW_NUMBER()` if you have more than one 'last' records and you want to select *all of them*.

**EDIT:**

This is a guess of how your actual query should look like (after the edit made in the OP):

```
SELECT Supplier, Item, Date, InvRsn, Qty, Price, Discount, ID
FROM (
    SELECT 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.CustSupp as Supplier, 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.Item as Item, 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.PostingDate as Date,
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.InvRsn AS InvRsn, 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.Qty as Qty, 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.UnitValue as Price, 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.DiscountFormula as Discount, 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.EntryId as ID,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.CustSupp, 
                                  dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.Item
                     ORDER BY dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.PostingDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MA_InventoryEntries 
            ON dbo.MA_InventoryEntriesDetail.EntryId = dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.EntryId
    WHERE 
        dbo.MA_InventoryEntries.CustSuppType = 6094849 ) t
WHERE t.rn = 1
ORDER BY Supplier, Item, Date
```

Comment: Thanks Giorgos, I've used the rank version and it worked perfectly. For me the question is solved.  :)

Comment: @Rabanito You're welcome. I have edited my original query to match the edit you made in the OP. It should be closer to what you actually used, I guess!